# Button Push App

Tags: android, android-studio, colors, push, android-contentprovider

I am learning to make apps using Android Studio (2.3.1).

First, user A on his phone pushes one of 4 colored buttons. This sends the result to user B on his phone with the exact same app, and displays the result to B (It can be a change in background color of the bottom button). The result should be a automatic push at the receiving end (without user B needing to refresh).

However, I'm not quite sure where to go after making the layout designs. I've read about content providers and such, but I have no idea where to start.... any help would be appreciated.

[Screen Shot][1]

****EDIT** I have taken advice from Shreyansh and Akshay More, but I would like a confirmation on the steps to solve this problem (want confirmation if my thought processes are right or not):

1. Get button states with setOnClickListener, saving that state as a binary value using Firebase Cloud Messaging (Is sharedpreferences necessary for this part??)
2. Client side retrieve this binary and identifies it
3. Display this color in letter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Firebase for push service if you want it to operate remotely.

Comment: I think I see what you mean. The "Realtime Database" or "Notification" functions?

Comment: In your android studio Tools > Firebase  > Cloud Messaging > set up Firebase Cloud Messaging.  Use [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/?utm_source=studio) to know more. Best of Luck